# How to specify the ListView SelectionMode property?

Tags: winforms, listview, selection

I have a ListView and I want to specify the selection (item) mode. In the equivalent WPF control there is the [ListView.SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode.aspx) property. Is there the same property for Windows Forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ListView.MultiSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.multiselect.aspx):  Gets or sets a value indicating whether multiple items can be selected.